# ncat listener - send data from client to script and script output to client

Tags: linux, netcat

I am trying to setup a simple TCP socket service on Linux (SLES 12) with ncat. The client will send a single string to socket that must be passed to a shell script. Based on the string the script will do some work and print the output through echo. This output must be passed back to the client so that client can display it to user.

Based on some search I wrote a simple service with ncat

```
ncat -l 9999 -c 'read i; /home/abhishek/hello.sh $i'
```

Below is the hello.sh script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello $1"
```

When I run a ncat client from localhost everthing works fine and I get back Hello *string* as expected. Both server and client close connection as expected.

```
echo abhishek | ncat -v localhost 9999
Ncat: Version 7.60 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to ::1:9999.
Hello abhishek
Ncat: 9 bytes sent, 17 bytes received in 0.04 seconds.
```

But when I run the client on some other machine there is no data sent back by server and both client and server close connection.

```
echo abhishek | ncat -v 192.168.1.12 9999
Ncat: Version 7.60 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to 129.221.43.94:9999.
Ncat: 9 bytes sent, 0 bytes received in 0.44 seconds.
```

I do not understand what I am doing wrong. Perhaps I am using ncat inappropriately.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/314550/45365

Comment: Thanks @hek2mgl. I used socat for listener and it works as expected when using ncat as client. I have trouble achieving same result with .NET client and will post a separate question for that.

Comment: Yeah, I would also use socat.